# Internal Server Error / Infinite Loop with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

#### Motivation

I am trying to redirect the URLs in the below format:

```
http://myapp/page-subpage-id.htm
http://myapp/page-subpage.htm
http://myapp/page.htm
```

To the following:

```
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage&id=id
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage
http://myapp/?page=page
```

#### Initial Solution

I have this content in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404&url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

It works perfect. But now my requirement changed to something like this:

```
http://myapp/page-subpage-id.htm
http://myapp/page-subpage.htm
http://myapp/page.htm
http://myapp/page-subpage-id
http://myapp/page-subpage
http://myapp/page
```

Should redirect to:

```
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage&id=id
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage
http://myapp/?page=page
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage&id=id
http://myapp/?page=page&sub=subpage
http://myapp/?page=page
```

#### Problem

So I changed my `.htaccess` file in three variants:

#### Variant I

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404&url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

#### Variant II

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404&url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

#### Variant III

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404&url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

#### Issues

But when I do so, I get the following issue:

[image]

And in the Apache Logs:

```
[Mon Jul 21 12:02:13.598400 2014] [core:error] [pid 2520:tid 860] [client 127.0.0.1:52488] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Jul 21 12:04:00.803400 2014] [core:error] [pid 2520:tid 848] [client 127.0.0.1:52507] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Jul 21 12:04:00.864400 2014] [core:error] [pid 2520:tid 848] [client 127.0.0.1:52508] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

#### Questions

1. Any ideas what is causing the issue?
2. What's the best solution to tackle something like this?
3. Is there a way to debug such kind of issues?

---

#### Solution

```
RewriteEngine On

# From StackOverflow
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+)(\.ptf)?$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3& [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^.]+)(\.ptf)?$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2& [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)(\.ptf)$ ./?page=$1& [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=$1& [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+)(\.htm)?$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^.]+)(\.htm)?$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2& [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.htm$ ./?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=404 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Works awesome for the first two conditions. But doesn't work for `/page`! :(

Comment: Okay, if I rewrite like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=$1& [L,QSA]`, it works! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

### Infinite Loop

There is no condition to prevent a rule such as

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

to rewrite itself over and over. After the rewrite, the `L` informs `mod-rewrite` that no further rules will be examined in the file. But that is not the end of the process. The rewritten url now falls through the same `.htaccess` again, until there is nothing left to rewrite. The `^(.*)$` is happy to catch the url again, and round and round it goes.

What you need, at the top of your `.htaccess`, is a rule to say that if the requested url is an existing folder or file, it should not be rewritten.

Try adding this before all other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

After a redirect to `./?page=etc`, the path part of the url points to a folder that exists. Therefore, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` is satisfied. The `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` fires, leaving the url untouched. And `mod-rewrite` exits without further looping.

Comment: If I put that way, it shows 404 for all the links! Doesn't work ya!